# spring boot: security autoconfiguration not applied (opaquetoken)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to configure oauth2 opaque token authorization using spring.

According to [oficial spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-sansboot):

> If the application doesn’t expose a SecurityFilterChain bean, then Spring Boot will expose the above default one.

When I'm trying to reach my endpoint without any authorization token, I'm able to reach it.

I need to add securityfilterchain manually:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken);
        return http.build();
    }
```

By other hand, documentation tells:

> If the application doesn’t expose an OpaqueTokenIntrospector bean, then Spring Boot will expose the above default one.

Nevertheless, when I start service I'm getting:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method filterChain in slab.tsystems.multipart.commonsupload.config.SecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector' in your configuration.
```

My related dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>10.7.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Why default behaviour is not applied?

Comment: Please add your application properties, you might be missing one

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Spring OAuth2 Resource Server documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-opaque-sansboot) you should declare a `Bean` returning the introspector or create a `CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector`.

Declare a `Bean` that returns the needed `OpaqueTokenIntrospector`:

```java
@Bean
public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
    return new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect", "clientid", "clientsecret");
}
```

Or if you want to customize the token introspection endpoint response, you can create a `CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector` that implements the `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` interface. Then pass to the configuration like this:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> {
                oAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer
                        .opaqueToken((opaqueTokenConfigurer -> {
                             opaqueTokenConfigurer.introspector(customOpaqueTokenInstropector);
                        }));
            }));
    return http.build();
}
```